# Não consigo encontrar o maior valor em um dicionário aleátorio

Tags: python, números-aleatórios

Eu preciso achar o maior valor dicionário utilizando uma função percorrendo com o laço 'for' eu consegui achar os valores de todos os outros conjuntos, menos os valores do dicionário.
Para gerar os valores do dicionário eu uso:

```
a = dict()
a['A'] = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
```

e para percorrer os valores eu uso:

```
for v in a.values():
    if v == 0:
        mai = v
    else:
        if v > mai:
            mai = v

print(f'O maior valor do dicionário é {mai}')
```

Porém ele sempre retorna o mesmo erro:

```
if v > mai:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

eu já tentei fazer uma lista receber apenas os valores do dicionário mas mesmo assim o erro persiste, se alguém puder ajudar eu ficaria agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso está acontecendo, pois o seu dicionário possui uma lista em `A`:

```
a['A'] = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
```

Você pode optar por algumas alterações no seu código, como iterar a posição `A` do dicionário:

```
for v in a['A']:
    if v == 0:
        mai = v
    else:
        if v > mai:
            mai = v
```

Ou quem sabe, verificar o tipo de dado presente em `v` com a função `type` dentro do loop e assim tomar uma decisão de como tratar:

```
for v in a.values():
    if type(v) == list:
        for x in v:
            if x > mai:
                mai = x
    elif type(v) == int:
      if v > mai:
          mai = v

print(f'O maior valor do dicionário é {mai}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns problemas com seu código, mas é bem simples de resolver. Vou tentar explicar bem. 
Primeiro vamos analisar a forma do dicionário que você criou.

```
a = dict() 
a['A'] = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
```

Printando seu dicionário vemos que ele possui apenas uma chave 'A' cujo valor é a lista de números aleatórios criados com o sample:

```
>>> print(a)
>>> {'A': [163, 126, 71, 15, 51, 120, 80, 182, 67, 169, 64, 161, 72, 21, 11, 118, 198, 134, 45, 141, 63, 199, 176, 168, 106, 65, 103, 123, 79, 1, 87, 159, 160, 155, 184, 151, 181, 99, 128, 111, 186, 101, 68, 75, 36, 147, 13, 50, 10, 135]}
```

Ao printar os valores do dicionário temos o resultado abaixo. Perceba que o valor é **uma lista dentro de uma lista** com os valores.

```
>>> print(a.values())
>>> dict_values([[163, 126, 71, 15, 51, 120, 80, 182, 67, 169, 64, 161, 72, 21, 11, 118, 198, 134, 45, 141, 63, 199, 176, 168, 106, 65, 103, 123, 79, 1, 87, 159, 160, 155, 184, 151, 181, 99, 128, 111, 186, 101, 68, 75, 36, 147, 13, 50, 10, 135]])
```

Agora que entendemos a estrutura do dicionário fica mais fácil de trabalhar. O código abaixo trás o resultado correto.

```
for value in a.values():
    maior = value[0] # Assuma que o primeiro valor é o maior e compare com os outros
    for x in value: # Nesse laço todos os valores vão ser comparados
        if x > maior:
            maior = x

print(f'O maior valor do dicionário é {maior}')
```

**Código alternativo**

Podemos simplesmente usar a função `max()`:

```
a = dict() 
a['A'] = sample(range(0, 200), 50)
values = a['A']
maior = max(values)

print(f'O maior valor do dicionário é {maior}')
```